# Mercurial - cleverencode - cleverdecode - multiple file patterns - mercurial.ini

Tags: mercurial, newline, hgrc

How do I specify the CRLF encode/decode option in mercurial.ini in Windows?

The documentation gives the following options:

```
[extensions]
win32text =
[decode]
** = cleverdecode:
[encode]
** = cleverencode:
```

for all files and,

```
[extensions]
win32text =
[decode]
**.txt = cleverdecode:
[encode]
**.txt= cleverencode:
```

for one kind of files (here .txt files).

What I need is to specify *.xml, *.java etc!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add more lines to the `[decode]` and `[encode]` sections:

```
[extensions]
win32text =

[decode]
**.txt = cleverdecode:
**.java = cleverdecode:
**.xml = cleverdecode:

[encode]
**.txt = cleverencode:
**.java = cleverencode:
**.xml = cleverencode:
```

By the way, the double-star matches any path and spans directory separators. See `hg help patterns` for more information about the so-called "globbing" options in Mercurial.